# Phantom warning: Unsupported configuration minimum font size is greater than current font size

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

XCode is giving me a warning about my minimum font size being greater than my current font size. When I click on the warning, it takes me to a XIB file but it only highlights the outer object, none of the inner objects which actually have a font size attribute. Just to be sure, I went through each object and made sure their minimum font size was smaller than their current font size, but Xcode still gives me this warning. What is this warning trying to point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by increasing the font size on a label object, then toggling off auto shrink on it, then rebuilding, then turning auto shrink back on.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios at play, and two solutions accordingly:

1) If you want to auto-shrink your label

- Increase the minimum font size of your label to something safe, say 16point
- Modify your code to set the font size to your desired font size at run-time

2) If you don't care about auto-shrink: simply change the "Autoshrink" setting to "Fixed Font Size" and this should correct the behavior regardless of what you have your font size set to in Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was difficult to identify which label was the problem.

Then I opened the storyboard as Source Code and search for minimumFontSize. I compared minimumFontSize with fontDescription's pointSize, to check which value was equal to or greater than the minimumFontSize.

Answer (score 0):

Replace minimum font size with minimum font scale.